# Несколько классов в одном java-файле

Tags: java

Можно ли в одном Java-файле содержать несколько классов и интерфейсов к ним ? Как лучше организовать их структуру, если нужно их все (к примеру, 4 класса и интерфейса) использовать ?

Comment: Я работаю с Eclipse, и он создает новый класс в своем джава-файлике.

Comment: а является ли хорошим тоном определять в одном файле несколько классов?

Comment: является плохим тоном

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
// файл MainClass.java

public class MainClass {

    // скрытый внутренний класс. Виден только внутри класса MainClass.
    private class MyInnerClass {
    }

    // скрытый интерфейс. Доступен внутри класса MainClass.
    private interface MyInnerInterface {
    }

    // Доступен везде, но создан может быть только изнутри MainClass
    public class MyPublicInnerClass {}

    // Доступен везде. Может быть создан в статическом контексте. 
    // В отличие от обычных inner-классов, не имеет доступа к членам MainClass.
    public static class MyStaticClass {}
}

// класс доступен в рамках пакета
class TestClass {
}

// интерфейс доступен в рамках пакета
interface TestInterface {
}
```

Только имейте в виду, что классы TestClass и TestInterface будут package-private, т.е. будут видимы только в рамках пакета.

Однако, всё же не следует злоупотреблять этими возможностями. Используйте их с осторожностью и по возможностью выносите классы в отдельные файлы.

Comment: cy6erGn0m +1 всё правильно написал =)

Comment: To @AleXpi

Плюсуйте, кликая в иконку "большой палец вверх".

Answer (score 5):

Да можно, но не стоит.

1. Почему НЕ стоит пихать интерфейс в тот же файл - потому что интерфейс сам по себе подразумевает, что его будут использовать другие люди, иначе толку от него?!
2. Почему НЕ стоит пихать классы в тот же файл - потому что люди не будут знать, как найти этот класс (это только в университетах код пишет и фиксит 1 человек).
3. Почему стоит пихать классы в тот же файл - если вы посмотрите в исходный код Жава, то вы найдете много примеров, когда абстрактный класс обьявлен как public, и в этом же файле лежит его дефолтная реализация. Нет смысла выносить этот класс в отдельный файл т.к. не предусмотрено, что кто-то будет им пользоватся, он нужен только этому паблик классу.

Стоит все же заметить, что обычно эти классы являются нестед классами по отношению к классу обьявленому как public.

Answer (score 2):

cy6erGn0m написал абсолютно все)
Остается только добавить, что лучше в один файл несколько классов не лепить. Это снижает читабельность кода, а после компиляции в байт-код Вы все равно получите три файла MainClass.class, MainClass$TestClass.class, MainClass$TestInterface.class.

Comment: static interface не написал - поленился :)