# внутренние классы, вложенные классы, анонимные классы

Tags: java

```
public class MainClass {

    // скрытый внутренний класс. Виден только внутри класса MainClass.
    private class MyInnerClass {
    }

    // скрытый интерфейс. Доступен внутри класса MainClass.
    private interface MyInnerInterface {
    }

    // Доступен везде, но создан может быть только изнутри MainClass
    public class MyPublicInnerClass {}

    // Доступен везде. Может быть создан в статическом контексте. 
    // В отличие от обычных inner-классов, не имеет доступа к членам MainClass.
    public static class MyStaticClass {}
}

// класс доступен в рамках пакета
class TestClass {
}

// интерфейс доступен в рамках пакета
interface TestInterface {
}
```

Класс TestClass является вложенным или каким? Если он в одном файле с MainClass, но не внутри этого класса?

Comment: Читайте статью https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/vidy-vlozhennyh-klassov + комметарии к ней

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я вот только оттуда, там не всегда всё правильно и + там нет того, что я хочу спросить

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я вот уже с Шилдта на Философию перешел, а до этого статьи, теперь читаю javarush ссылку вашу, возможно найдется человек и ответит на вопросы выше подробно, было бы круто.

Comment: Это про несколько классов в одном файле https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18305/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-java-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5

Answer (score 0):

Нет, он не является вложенным. Вы можете хоть программу на миллион строчек запихать в один файл, но от этого пострадает только читаемость вашего кода. Поэтому и надо разделять классы на отдельные файлы и пакеты. Вложенный класс - тот который находится внутри другого класса, у вас это - public class MyPublicInnerClass {}