# Странности с локальными классами связанные с модификаторами доступа. Откуда растут ноги этих странностей?

Tags: java, android, классы

Ну понятно, что смысла нет использовать модификаторы доступа для объявления локальных классов. Но вот интересно:

1) почему в локальных классах разрешено объявлять поля, методы, конструкторы и private и public и protected???

2) если объявлять два локальных классов в одном методе, то даже если один из полей одного класса будет иметь private модификатор доступа, то это никак не помешает другому классу использовать этот private поле.
  Например:

```
public class Catcher {
    public int BookCatcher(){
        class Book{
            private int color;
            String name;
            int countOfPages;

            Book(){}
        }

        class Ou{
            Ou(){
                Book book = new Book();

                book.color=5;
                Log.i("Room8000", String.valueOf(book.color));
            }
        }

        Book book = new Book();
        Ou ou = new Ou();
        return book.color;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Catcher catcher = new Catcher();
        catcher.BookCatcher();
    }
}
```

result:

```
2020-04-22 17:09:58.410 20627-20627/com.example.android.javaoop I/Room8000: 5
```

3) но вот если этот самый private поле сделать static то компилятор вспоминает, что надо ругаться.

компилятор:

> inner classes cannot have static declarations

4) да и если вместо private использовать protected то можно убедится, что нет вообще необходимости добавить extends к вызывающему данное поле классу. (ну этот пункт можно и не учесть как странность, но все же)

И так вопросы:

В чем смысл таких допущении в языке Java? Это баги или имеют какое то логичное объяснение, которую я просто не вижу? А если баг, то как получается что в течении столько обновлении версии java к этой проблеме не уделили ни малейшего внимания?

Answer (score 1):

На будущее, по правилам stack сообществ один вопрос = один вопрос. 4 вопроса внутри одного задавать не стоит, даже если они как-то связаны между собой

1) а почему нет? Тот факт, что вы создали класс внутри метода не означает, что он должен работать иначе. Если вы создадите private inner class, то у него тоже можно создавать public методы и поля. Просто нет смысла добавлять другой интерпретатор для внутренних классов

2) почитайте подробнее про модификаторы доступа. private = доступный в этом же файле. default - в этом пакете. protected - в этом файле и наследованных классах. Т.к. вложенные в метод классы не могут находится в разных файлах у вас нет инструмента изолировать поля одного от другого

3) inner классы не могут иметь  static полей и методов, что вам и сказала IDE. Вообще никакие вложенные классы никаких static элементов не могут содержать. Если в одном файле записаны несколько классов еще можно, но тогда они не вложенные, просто в одном файле лежат, а не внутри друг друга

4) опять же, проблема в том как в java интерпретируется private и protected. Как я говорил выше, нет возможности изолировать поля созданных в одном методе классов друг от друга.

В целом вложенные в методы классы можно отнести к bad practices, как и inner классы. Первые малоэффективны, а вторые еще и не безопасны по памяти. Если их использование в конкретном случае правда упрощает код, то можно воспользоваться, но в большинстве случаев их можно избежать не потеряв в эффективности и читаемости кода. Используйте только статичные внутренние классы

```
public class A {
   static public/private/default class B{
   }
}
```

Потому что без static класс становится зависим от экземпляра родителя и хранит на него ссылку. То есть код

```
public class A{
   public class B{
   }
}
```

эквивалентен

```
public class A{
   static public class B{
       A parent;
       B(A parent){
           this.parent = parent;
       }
   }
}
```

В результате есть риск сохранить объект класса B, а он не даст сборщику убить класс A. Если класс А - это активити, то можно нахватать много проблем по незнанию

Вывод. Из все этой простыни выносим следующее: если нужно создать класс внутри другого, то он (желательно)должен быть static. Классы внутри методов лучше не использовать вообще, т.к. это малополезно и это все те же inner классы. И внимательно читаем  принципы работы модификаторов доступа, т.к. в java они работают не совсем по парадигме ООП

UPD Как верно заметил ТС в комментариях, я не точно выразился по правилу "private доступен внутри файла". Нужно сделать оговорку про несколько не вложенных друг в друга классов в одном файле. Например код из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/18308/318053) ответа  распадается на 3 разных class файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Соседствующие" классы разошлись по файлам, а inner классы остались вну ри родителей и не получили отдельных файлов. И внутри этих class файлов работает правило "private доступен во всем этом файле"

Comment: " Т.к. вложенные в метод классы не могут находится в разных файлах у вас нет инструмента изолировать поля одного от другого" минутку. А как же это? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/18308/318053, ну в смысле, в одном файле находятся, но не имеют доступа к private данным. Я во всяком случае проверил через IDE. Поэтому ваши утверждения "private = доступный в этом же файле."  + "Как я говорил выше, нет возможности изолировать поля созданных в одном методе классов друг от друга." для меня не понятны.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan  вы правы, немного преувеличил, т.к. имел в виду ситуацию один файл - один "верхний" класс. Если в файле есть не вложенные друг в друга классы, то да, они друг от друга изолированы, т.к. при компиляции все равно будут превращены в два разных class файла. Проверьте в IDEA, например, скопируйте туда код из того ответа, создайте объекты этих типов и увдите в папке out отдельные файлы под MainClass, TestClass и TestInterface. Соответственно правило "private доступно внутри фала" работает, просто после компиляции

Comment: @RubenKubalyan добавил это в ответ

Comment: Ну допустим. Просто интересно было, что таки есть механизм изолирования внутри одного .java файла, поэтому на основе этого и возник вопрос "так почему при nested class та же самое изоляция не работает?". Ну есть версия что джава разработчики просто пропустили этот пункт и не потратили время и нервы на ее устранение. А вы как думаете? Если в чем то неправ, буду рад узнать в чем именно.